# Spring Boot - Azure Key Vault Managing Vault Access secrets

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, security, azure-keyvault

im developing spring boot applications (microservices) backends for my frontend services.
I want to start using Azure as running infrastructure for these services.
I also want to user Azure Key Vault because if my understanding is right it gives me the following benefits:

- Logical grouping of secrets in the same space/vault
- Possibility of HSM
- Logging/Auditing
- One Place to retrieve/change secrets on which may many applications depend without touching the aplications.

What i dont get is how to handle the vault access in my spring boot applications.
When i use the azure-key-vault spring boot starters i have to set the access in applications.properties like in this tutorial: [How to use the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#configure-and-compile-your-app)

But in my opinion i just secured my secrets with an other layoer of id/password which are again in plain text in my .propertes file and end up in the version control system.

What are ways to handle this and where is the extra security the Vault should deliver?
What point am i missing?

I want to deploy my spring boot backends as jars in azure web app ressources if this matters for the question.

Thanks ina advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the Azure SDK for Key Vault. Azure Key Vault provides a centralized and secure repository that can authentication multiple people, service principals (apps), or managed identities (more on that in a second) with different permission sets. Like maintainers might be able to list, get, and set secrets, keys, and certificates, while apps and managed identities might only be able to get and maybe list (if you need to enumerate all secrets for some reason, like some app configuration startup routines to fill all secrets matching some pattern). This provides a means to control who can access what, and to what degree.

Ideally - and as recommended - you use managed identities whenever possible. [Managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) allow you to run your app with a particular ID that is managed by Azure. No password is supplied. The app runs as that identity, [which you can grant access to in a Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) with whatever permissions make sense for your needs.

The samples [like the one you referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#configure-and-compile-your-app) tend to favor simplistic examples to explain a concept, but we have realized and are trying to update docs like this to recommend managed identities.

However, application secrets can still be utilized fairly safely. A typical approach is that only a few people know these secrets (they themselves could be stored in Key Vault, and only a few people could have access to that key vault to list and get values - since you'd need access to add them anyway), but then add them as environment variables in your application. Azure and other services (GitHub, AppVeyor, etc.) often have ways of securing secrets.

For example, your application could use environment variables you set up before hand security like so:

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID="some GUID - doesn't really have to be secret, but doesn't hurt"
AZURE_CLIENT_ID="secret GUID for service principal ID"
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="secret value for service principal ID"
```

Then, using our Azure.* packages, you can have your code do something like this:

```java
SecretAsyncClient secretAsyncClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
  .vaultUrl("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/")
  .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
  .buildAsyncClient();

String secret;
secretAsyncClient.getSecret("secretName")
  .subscribe(secretWithVersion ->
    secret = secretWithVersion.getValue());
```

You could use that or - better - a different service principal for development. While developing the Azure Key Vault SDK, I set up my own SP I use for development purposes only, while our test runners use a different one using variables in [Azure DevOps pulled from an authenticated Key Vault connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault).

You could further extend that to different dev, test, and prod environments that could each have a separate service principal to access different vaults (perhaps keep the prod vaults more secure with fewer authorized applications/people).

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have further questions.